# Update from app store stuck on "downloading.."

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, updates, downloading, google-play-store

There are three apps that needs an update on my device, I've got an always-on 3G connection and it's working (I can use whatever app I need), but when trying to download the update from the app store the progress bar reach the end (100% downloaded, should have saved it entirely) but it won't install the new update and the page on the store keeps telling "Downloading..".

I tried clearing the store cache/data several times but didn't work, I tried clearing the app's cache too (the one that needs to be updated) but it wasn't useful.

How can I solve? I didn't do anything to my un-rooted semi-new phone (Galaxy S plus with gingerbread)

Comment: I noticed that you said you tried clearing the cache & data for the Google Play Store app, and the target app's cache. Can you try to **uninstall** the application and install it from scratch? That might help.

Comment: Do you mean the google store or the app that is trying to update? I have three apps: whatsapp, fb messenger and battery saver 2x battery by sam lu (I disabled this too but didn't work)

Comment: Possible related question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103066/app-installs-get-stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by reinstalling the store update (i.e. switching it back to the basic market app and let it update again)